# email link open iframe and change source

Tags: javascript, php, html, iframe

Thank you anyone and everyone in advance

So I have an automated email that we send to clients with a url and unique refernce at the end that will display their page , I want to be able to create a link in the email that will open a page on a different url that has an iframe and then display in that iframe the original url just changing the unique reference each time.

I have started like this but do not know if I am on complete wrong track

the email link like this

```
<a href="http://iframeaddresshere.html?link=uniquereference"> Press here </a>
```

then the html with the iframe has this

```
<script>
function getValue()
{
  //start by loading my url here 
  var url = window.location.href;

var link = getValue();
if (link.length){//check if you got a value
document.getElementByName('iframe1').src = link ;//set the src
}
</script>


<iframe src="https://mywebaddress/" name="iframe1" width="100%" height="400" frameBorder="0" align="middle"></iframe>
```

Obviously these are not the actual links they are just to illustrate :)

Comment: You tagged php, and this question is a good job for php, doing it with js produces chaos and long loading times

Comment: By the way your js is in an endless loop, wich is not good ( getValue())

Answer (score 0):

I would implement this in php, to short the code and to give you advanced control on how the url is processed:

```
<iframe src="<?php echo $_GET["url"];?>">Update Browser!</iframe>

http://yoursitecode?url=google.com
```

As Quentin pointed out, this code is open to XSS wich isnt good.
You should store token / url combinations in your database, to prevent users from accessing everything they want...

Comment: **Danger**: This code is [vulnerable to XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS) User input needs escaping before being inserted into an HTML document!.